# Change layout in EasyAdmin4 CollectionField

Tags: easyadmin, symfony5.4, php-8.2

I'm new into Symfony(5.4) + EasyAdmin(4) bundle.
I need to display a CollectionField in full-screen mode and display all the fields in one row, maximum two rows. [Click here for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcgKz.png)

I tried to achieve this by modifying only the CSS, but the changes didn't work.
I also attempted to create a custom Twig template and use Bootstrap templates, but no matter what I do, the form always appears with each field on a separate row and taking up only half of the page.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Any ideas on how I could resolve it? Thank you.